# Inheritance in generic composite pattern

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, composite

For what I want to achieve I ended up with some kind of generic composite pattern.

```
public abstract class Component
{
}

public abstract class Composite<ChildType> : Component where ChildType : Component
{
    public readonly Dictionary<int, ChildType> children;

    public Composite()
    {
        children = new Dictionary<int, ChildType>();
    }

    public void AddChild(ChildType child, int childPosition)
    {
        if (children.ContainsKey(childPosition))
        {
            children.Remove(childPosition);
        }

        children.Add(childPosition, child);
    }
}
```

With the pattern above, I have the following deriving classes.

```
public class A : Composite<B>
{
}

public class B : Composite<C>
{
}

public class C : Component
{
}
```

Now, this ended up working very well for my purposes. Things developed and I felt the need of extracting some functionality from `B` into a base class and creating two subclasses from `B`. Let's call the base class `BaseB` and its subclasses `B1` and `B2`.

I want `B1` to act as if inheriting from `Composite<B2>` and `B2` from `Composite<C>` (just like the old B class). As for `A`, it should be able to have children of any subclass of `BaseB`. But naturally it wants me to provide a type argument for `BaseB`, so I ended up providing the type `Component`. Is there a way to avoid specifying a type argument for `BaseB`?

```
//public class A : Composite<BaseB<Component>> This works
public class A : Composite<BaseB> // this doesn't work
{
}

public class BaseB<GetItFromTheSubClass> : Composite<GetItFromTheSubClass> where GetItFromTheSubClass : Component
{
}

public class B1 : BaseB<B2>
{
}

public class B2 : BaseB<C>
{
}

public class C : Component
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a solution other than:

- either put the extra functionality of BaseB to an external class and have B1 and B2 use this class (static or instance)
- or maybe extension methods for B1 and B2: [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Neither of them are particularly nice or easy.
(B1 and B2 could inherit BaseB functionality as interface, but then again there is the question of how you avoid double implementation of the functionality).